# Advices for Burning Man Festival

Tags: air-travel, planning, tips-and-tricks, adventure, burning-man

I plan to go with a friend to the Burning Man festival in 2016 and I want to know if there's anything to know about this festival before I lock in my plans.

I'll leave from France by plane, but I have some question about the travel to Black Rock. Which airport should I choose? How should I go to Black Rock? Car rental or bus?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE, but this is too broad to get any good answers, so please narrow down your question.  Do you have flights booked yet?  Where do you arrive in the US?

Comment: Since you don't know your plans yet, this question is kinda broad. Moreover it fits the WANTA debate, and is thus [not allowed on TSE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Indeed, as it stands, you are asking TSE help to plan and schedule your trip to Black Rock City. You might want to rephrase it by narrowing down it's focus.

Comment: The nearby cities are Reno and San Fransisco. There is the Burner Express bus from both. Flights are likely to be cheaper to San Fransisco, although there are direct flights from London to Reno.

Comment: @jpatokal I made this post to know which flights to take !
JoErNan0 i don't want a debate, I just want advices from people who already went there
Carl Thanks !

Comment: @Carl There are direct flights to Reno from London? You mean charters specifically for this event or actual scheduled airline service? The latter seems very unusual for such a small-market airport. Looking at the airport on google maps, there were exactly 2 planes parked there when the areal photo was taken, a turboprop and a small regional jet.

Comment: @reirab strange but true. There are cheap, direct London-Reno flights, and lots of buses for a few euros from France to London.

Answer (score 4):

(disclaimer, I've never been there)

Have a look at (and related pages):
http://burningman.org/event/preparation/getting-there-and-back/

and 
http://survival.burningman.org/your-survival-in-brc/survival-checklist/

Black Rock is in the middle of the desert and **you need to be self-sufficient** or you will not enjoy your stay

Depending on your involvement in the event, you might need to rent a van (or something similar) to haul everything you need (water, water, food, water, food and more water...).

As for specifics, you should land in San Francisco it will be easier (and maybe cheaper) to rent a van and buy everything you need.

Good luck and Have fun.